# Using someone else's font license

Tags: font-licensing, latex

I am currently writing my dissertation and I would love to use a specific typeface set (Minion Pro, Minion Math, Myriad Pro). I do not own a license for them, but I know someone who does.

So, this might be a naïve question, but I'll give it a try: I wonder if allowing that person to compile the LaTeX sources for me (with no retribution) would violate their license. The thesis will be released in print, in PDF, and also the LaTeX sources will be released under an open-source license (but, of course, will only compile if the machine has access to the fonts).

Comment: I think this is *far* more a legal question than a design question. However, a license means someone *can* use the font on *their* system. Where the actual project comes from is irrelevant.

Comment: Closed this because this involves legal advice

Comment: I hope you mean _attribution_ and not _retribution_.

Comment: I am **not** a lawyer, @Vikas

Answer (score 2):

That person number 2 has the right to use the mentioned fonts in his computer. If his license isn't limited to "personal projects only" and allows attempts to earn money he can for ex. legally process your writings for money of for $0,00 as long as he doesn't include copies of font files to them.

He can legally convert texts and formulas which contain those fonts to curves (=outline) and then the documents are readable without having the fonts, but no more editable.

I have seen licenses which explicitly deny any forms of transferring rights to a 3rd person. That means person 2 cannot legally hire his purchased font to you. I do not know what your local law says if you hire and use his computer which has all kinds of fonts and other software installed. I guess it would be illegal if some of font or other software licenses are pointed to a person. It would be legal if all licenses pointed to certain machine.

Some fonts are allowed to be embedded into PDF. It's not always legal. It's legal only if the license allows embedding to PDF and there's very likely limitations. Check this https://www.printivity.com/insights/2020/09/13/how-to-embed-fonts-in-pdfs/.

BTW. If I was able to write scientific or studying material texts worth publishing I would use generally available fonts or free fonts that are allowed to be redistributed. Finest typography would be secondary. A substitute font may change meaning in cases where exact placements are important. I would convert every formula to curves to reduce the possibilities of unwanted versions to occur.